# property name of a textfield

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my iphone apps I have two textfields.  I put a value in the name property of each textfield, but in the code I want to get the name of the textfield itself. I tried `textfield.name` but that does not work.  How can I have the value of the property name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean name like in Interface Builder Identity? Then the answer is no, you can't access it programatically. It's there only to help you tell them apart from each other inside Interface Builder. However the tag property is accessible both in code and in IB (first tab in IB)